# Downloading dropbox directory onto pc

Tags: download, desktop

I Had my pc cleaned up and now need to download my entire Dropbox directory and all files onto my pc. (I can work on it online, but I find it so slow and confusing. ) Please explain to me How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Install Dropbox on each device you want, log into Dropbox and it will synchronize on each device. I have Dropbox on my computer and the files are there for me to use at will